# Error: Column doesn't exist in table (Foreign Key referencing)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-scripts

**Question** 
I am trying to link the ID column from the Customer's table to C_ID in the Purchases table. I am still learning SQL so I have a light knowledge and am not sure why this error is occuring. If someone could offer up a solution and point where I've went wrong that would be great.

**Error Message** 
[image]

**SQL Code**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (

ID INTEGER,
Firstname VARCHAR (15),
Lastname VARCHAR (15),
Address VARCHAR (254),
Postcode VARCHAR (8),
Email VARCHAR (254),
Phoneno INTEGER,
Points INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Purchases (

C_ID INTEGER,
GameName VARCHAR(30),
ConsoleType VARCHAR (20),
Price VARCHAR (254),
PaymentType VARCHAR (20),
Date TIMESTAMP,
PointsGained INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (C_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Customer(ID)
);
```

Comment: Error messages are sometimes very specific.  This is one of those occasions.  If you want to be a programmer, reading and interpreting error messages are skills you need.  This one is so clear and specific that it suggest that you might not have read it at all.  Having said that, sometimes the messages are vague, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misplaced the primary key and foreign key column also you didn't add Purchase table primary key column

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases 
(
ID INTEGER, -- Primary key column 
C_ID INTEGER,
GameName VARCHAR(30),
ConsoleType VARCHAR (20),
Price VARCHAR (254),
PaymentType VARCHAR (20),
Date TIMESTAMP,
PointsGained INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) -- Replace ID with C_ID
    REFERENCES Customer(ID)  
);
```

Comment: beat me by a second :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Ha ha that too both of us came up with similar thoughts :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a column named `ID` in your `Purchases` table.
Seems to me it should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases (
    ID INTEGER,
    C_ID INTEGER,
    GameName VARCHAR(30),
    ConsoleType VARCHAR (20),
    Price VARCHAR (254),
    PaymentType VARCHAR (20),
    Date TIMESTAMP,
    PointsGained INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) REFERENCES Customer(ID)
);
```

So that the `ID` column is the primary key and the `C_ID` column is the foreign key to customers.