# from existing value Update column using comma-separated values in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

from existing value Update column using comma-separated values in SQL Server

```
tbl 
id name rev_code
1  aaa  rev1,rev2,rev3
2  bbb  rev2,rev3
3  ccc  rev1,rev2
4  ddd  rev3,rev2
```

i want update where rev_code='rev3' need to add end of with , like rev1,rev2,rev3,rev5

expecting output

```
id name rev_code
1  aaa  rev1,rev2,rev3,rev5
2  bbb  rev2,rev3,rev5
3  ccc  rev1,rev2
4  ddd  rev3,rev2,rev5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **best** option would be to **normalize** your database:
Get rid of that `rev_code` column and turn it into a new table, linked with a foreign key constraint to the current table.

If that's impossible, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET rev_code = rev_code + ',rev5'
WHERE ','+ rev_code + ',' LIKE '%,rev3,%'
AND ','+ rev_code + ',' NOT LIKE '%,rev5,%'
```

Comment: if rev_code started with rev3 means your like statement fails.

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy  - No, He has added leading comma in both LHS and RHS

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy by adding leading and trailing commas in both sides of the likes I'm ensuring that only correct values would pass. if this was a string of comma delimiter numbers, and you would search for `2`, without that trick you would get false positives on any member that contains `2` - like `21`, `3245` and so on.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled.  Already rev5 in rev_code means it will add again rev5?

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. error?

Comment: This is yet another reason why you need to normalize your database. the `rev_code` is probably too short for the newly created strings generated by the update statement.

Answer (score 1):

Stop storing comma separated values in a column it violates *First Normal form*. Consider changing your database design

At worst case use this update to get the result

```
UPDATE Yourtable
SET    [rev_code] = [rev_code] + ',rev5'
WHERE  Charindex('rev3', [rev_code]) > 0
```

Comment: [we keep thinking of the same answers :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36288648/3094533)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Yes  :)

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. error?

Comment: @mailtoasp - What is the length of `rev_code` column

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will `rev5` for the rev_code if there is `rev3` and `rev5` already not exists.

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET    rev_code = rev_code + ',rev5'
WHERE  rev_code NOT LIKE '%rev5%' AND rev_code LIKE '%rev3%'
```

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE table1 SET rev_code=rev_code +',rev5' 
where  rev_code like '%rev3%' and Charindex('rev5', [rev_code])= 0
```

edited:

```
 UPDATE table1 SET rev_code= rev_code +',rev5' 
 where rev_code  IS NOT NULL and rev_code like '%rev3%' and Charindex('rev5', [rev_code])= 0
```

> Check rev_code column size.

And as @Zohar Peled said, it is a bad idea while storing comma separated values.

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: error?? Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @mailtoasp, Can you check your 'rev_code' column size.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch...you have your db design wrong so i will first suggest to create additional one-to-many table where you would store fields: originalTableRecordId | rev_code

then you find all records in that table that have particular rev_code value and add new one to those that meet criteria.

If you cant change your db structure then you have to go with either "WHERE rev_code like '%rev3%' " (which will be awfully slow) or with fulltext search (which is a huge overkill)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
UPDATE table 
SET rev_code = rev_code+',rev5' 
WHERE rev_code LIKE '%rev3%' (OR RIGHT(rev_code,4) = 'rev3')
```